# If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty = \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a} f'(x)/g'(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)/g(x) = L$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, solution-verification

I would like some verification on this proof that I have written and would also like to have some feedback wherever possible.

> Question: Prove the following theorem: If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty = \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$

My attempt for this proof is as follows:

By the definition of the limit, $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, if $|x - a| < \delta$, then $\left|\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} - L\right| < \varepsilon$.

So first thing we should notice, is that $g'(x) \neq 0$ for $|x - a| < \delta$. Then this also implies that $g(x) - g(a) \neq 0$ for $|x - a| < \delta$ (Rolle's).

Now, by the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem, we can write $\dfrac{f'}{g'}$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}\tag{*}
\dfrac{f(x) - f(a)}{g(x) - g(a)} = \dfrac{f'(z)}{g'(z)}
\end{equation*}
for some $z \in (a - \delta, a + \delta)$. And $|z - a| < \delta$ as required.

Now,
\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \dfrac{f(x) - f(a)}{g(x) - g(a)} \cdot \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x) - f(a)} \cdot \dfrac{g(x) - g(a)}{g(x)}
\end{equation*}
where $f(x) - f(a) \neq 0$, $g(x) - g(a) \neq 0$ and $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in (a - \delta, a + \delta)$, because $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty = \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$. So these limits imply that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x) - f(a)} = \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{g(x) - g(a)}{g(x)} = 1
\end{equation*}
So it follows that $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ can be made as close to $\dfrac{f(x) - f(a)}{g(x) - g(a)}$ as required by choosing $x \in (a - \delta, a + \delta)$. So with $(*)$, it follows that
\begin{equation*}
\left|\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} - L\right| < 2\varepsilon
\end{equation*}
for $x \in (a - \delta, a + \delta)$ as required.

Not sure if this proof is complete or is the right approach. Would like some advice wherever possible. Thanks

Comment: Neither of $f,g$ is defined at $x=a$.

Comment: @Justauser so would I have to prove it using two different cases when $x \in (a - \delta, a)$ and when $x \in (a, a + \delta)$?

Comment: Yes, but the same proof on the left applies to the right too. You need to apply Cauchy MVT not for $[x,a]$ but $[x, a-\delta/2]$.

Comment: @Justauser and then the other would be for $(a + \delta/2, x)$ im assuming?

Comment: Yes. The proof is totally symmetric, but you really have to be careful.